# Force IIS server to return a 304

Tags: iis, http-headers, httpresponse

I am working on fixing a bug, and for testing purposes, I need a way to force my IIS server to return a 304 response code from a simple GET request. I do not have much experience working with IIS servers, so I am wondering if anyone has an idea on how I could do this. For testing and debugging purposes, the simplest manner would be appreciated so that I can constantly reproduce the behaviour.

Before learning that the server has to be IIS, I was able to do this using a perl script, in which I would create my own server and http::response and alter the header. But this method is no longer viable.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't know enough about IIS to answer this properly. Look at properties for the IIS application, and where a success would be returned, return a 304. There is a tab that covers error conditions. I believe a simpler solution would be to write a quick and dirty asp page, and have it return the 304. ASP's default language is VBScript, so it should not be too hard to do.

Comment: I have not worked with ASP or VBScript (still an undergrad). I've googled around, and found some examples of how pages return responses in ASP.Net, but they appear to just be snippets of code, and I am not quite sure how it all fits together. Is this something I could learn relatively easy, without having to go to great lengths (currently) in understanding ASP/VBScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For Classic ASP**

Since you mention classic ASP, here is how to return a 304. Just add a page under your website directory, and put in this code:

```
<%@ Language=VBScript %>
<%
    Response.Status = "304 You have a 304 error"
%>
```

Then in the browser you can just request the above page (it should do a get request).

More info at the [Response.Status](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525844%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) page at MSDN.

**For ASP.NET**

If you need to use ASP.NET, you can use Visual Studio to add a new Web Forms page. When you do this there should be multiple files. You just need to find the file that ends in "aspx.cs" (or aspx.vb). Inside the `Page_Load` function, just add the following line.

For C#:

```
Response.StatusCode = 304;
```

For VB:

```
Response.StatusCode = 304
```

More info at the [Response.StatusCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.httpresponse.statuscode%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) page at MSDN.

Comment: So to confirm: I create a .aspx file (lets say file304.aspx), simply place that code inside the file, upload the file to my server, and then do a GET request to <server>/file304.aspx?

Comment: @Tesla - Sorry this is for the old asp (not asp.net). Based on your comments this is what I thought you were looking for.

Comment: According to previous comments, I believe it can still work. I am just not versed with any ASP at all. The file extension would simply be .asp then?

Comment: @Tesla - yes the extension is .asp

Comment: @Tesla - I added instructions for ASP.NET as well.

Comment: Wonderful answer, which is why I commented and didn't answer. I have forgotten some of this stuff.

Comment: Perfect, that is exactly what I needed. Appreciate the help guys.